# Join in MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a database and Im using PHP to connect to the database and query it. Theres two tables Drivers and Teams. The drivers have the following fields:

- id
- forename
- surname
- nationality
- team_id

The Teams have the following fields:
 - id
 - name
 - engine
 - nationality
 - based
 - principle

I am trying create a query to show the drivers forename and surname, nationality, and team names.

I have used the following code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Drivers
    JOIN Teams
    ON Drivers.id = Teams.id");

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>forename</th>
        <th>surname</th>
        <th>Nationality</th>
        <th>Team</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['forename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nationality'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

and this is the result I get:

```
forename    surname Nationality Team
Sebastian   Vettel  Austrian    Red Bull
Mark    Webber  Italian Ferrari
Jenson  Button  British Mclaren
Lewis   Hamilton    German  Mercedes
Fernando    Alonso  British Lotus
Felipe  Massa   Indian  Force India
Michael Schumacher  Swiss   Sauber
Nico    Rosberg Italian Torro Rosso
Kimi    Raikkonen   British Williams
Romain  Grosjean    British Caterham
Jerome  d'Ambrosio  Spanish HRT
Paul    di Resta    Russian Marussia
```

however the results doesn't show all the drivers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you mean by they do not show all drivers? Please give an example of a driver thats not shown (maybe he has no team?)

Comment: if a driver has no team, this driver won't show as you're using `INNER JOIN` if you want all drivers to show even if they don't have a team, you should use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: forename surname Nationality
Sebastian Vettel German
Mark Webber Australian
Jenson Button British
Lewis Hamilton British
Fernando Alonso Spanish
Felipe Massa Brazilian
Michael Schumacher German
Nico Rosberg German
Kimi Raikkonen Finnish
Romain Grosjean French
Jerome d'Ambrosio Belgian
Paul di Resta British
Nico Hulkenberg German
Kamui Kobayashi Japanese
Sergio Perez Mexican
Daniel Ricciardo Australian
Jean-Eric Vergne French
Pastor Maldonado Venezualan
Bruno Senna Brazilian
Heikki Kovalainen Finnish
Vitaly Petrov Russian
Pedro de la Rosa Spanish

thats the full drivers table

Comment: I think you're understanding something wrong, your tables structure is wrong. drivers table should have team_id in it, which references the id of the team where the driver is, and the join should be on Drivers.team_id=teams.id, now you're joining on Driver ID and Team ID I am sure you're getting wrong results where by chance the driver id is = to the team id

Answer (score 2):

You need to join on drivers.team_id not drivers.id.

You should also do a left join, so that drivers without teams are still selected:

```
SELECT * FROM Drivers LEFT JOIN Teams ON Drivers.team_id = Teams.id
```

Comment: +1. Good catch on the JOIN criteria. It's best practice to avoid the `*` in the SELECT list, and reference the specific columns to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: Don't `SELECT *` if you're not going to use every field, it's a waste of resources. To get only `forename`, `surname`, `nationality`, and `name`, you might modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT D.forename, D.surname, D.nationality, T.name
FROM Drivers AS D
JOIN Teams AS T ON Drivers.id = Teams.id;
```

Now, as for some drivers not appearing, there are a couple likely culprits:

1 - `JOIN` in MySQL is a synonym for `INNER JOIN`:

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html))

An `INNER JOIN` shows only rows that exist in BOTH tables. So if you have Drivers that are not associated with any Team, or vice versa, an `INNER JOIN` will exclude them from the result set. If you want to see every Driver, use `Drivers LEFT JOIN Teams`; if you want to see every team, use `Drivers RIGHT JOIN Teams`. (The `RIGHT` and `LEFT` keywords refer to the order in which the tables appear in the query, so `Drivers LEFT JOIN Teams` is the same thing as `Teams RIGHT JOIN Drivers`.)

A commonly-used resource around these parts for better understanding the different types of `JOIN` is http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/.

2 - Are you certain you have `JOIN`ed these tables using the correct `ON` condition? Your `id` columns for these two tables are different; Driver Bob may have `Drivers.id = 4341`, but he's unlikely to also be a member of the Team that has  `Team.id = 4341`. From your description of the tables, it looks like you want to match `Drivers.team_id` with `Team.id`, so your query would be further modified as follows:

```
SELECT D.forename, D.surname, D.nationality, T.name
FROM Drivers AS D
JOIN Teams AS T ON Drivers.team_id = Teams.id;
```

Comment: +1. For good example of qualifying column references, and specifying columns to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Drivers
    LEFT JOIN Teams
    ON Drivers.team_id = Teams.id");

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>forename</th>
        <th>surname</th>
        <th>Nationality</th>
        <th>Team</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['forename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nationality'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If you're going to rate something down, be man enough to explain why please. I make mistakes like everyone else and am perfectly fine with being corrected.

Comment: the -1 isn't me, but I think it was because your answer is a copy paste of the OP's code, with a fix but no explanation...

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I think a note about what change(s) were made and why those changes were made would be more helpful to OP, than requiring OP to wade through the code to compare, to determine which lines were changed.

Comment: I downvoted, because your query was wrong, and watched your answer for corrections before leaving a comment. When you fixed what was apparently a typo, I removed the downvote. Goosfraba. (Though I agree that code blocks sans-elaboration make for low quality answers.)